# Raster To Ascii cmd-line tool

Tags: raster

Where can I find a tool like [ArcGis: Raster_to_ASCII](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Raster_to_ASCII/001200000005000000/)

Provided that the tool **MUST** be accessible through command line interface.

Answer (score 3):

you can use GDAL (ArcGIS is based on it), and more specifically [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html).Here is the command line :

gdal_translate -of AAIGrid inputfile outputfile

Note 1 : there are different ASCII output with GDAL, you have a list [here](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html)

Note 2 : If you work with ArcGIS and you need a specific tool, you can also create a model with ArcGIs, export it in Python, and launch the python script with a command line.

Comment: If you're not familiar with GDAL and are using windows may I recommend fwtools as a good starting point. It is an installer with the basic GDAL tools: http://fwtools.maptools.org/ open the FWTools Shell to access GDAL commands; there is also some good help in the HTML directory on the formats and command line tools.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson - Please don't recommend FWTools, it is waaay out of date and is [no longer being updated](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries#FWTools). The GDAL/OGR version in FWTools is 1.7 from 2010... The [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) or [GIS Internals](http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/) GDAL binaries should be used/recommended instead.

Comment: @Luke fair enough, I only recommend it for simplicity but should have mentioned the issues with the comment. It would do the task that is required and doesn't involve the advanced install requirements of OSGeo4W. Personally I use http://gisinternals.com/sdk/; the bit about setting the environment settings can be a bit off-putting for the beginner.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson - GISInternals has a simple .msi installer as well which sets env. vars. But which compiler version/plugin/python bindings to install can be a bit off-putting.  Someone needs to set up a "just works" Windows installer again.